# Вывести кнопки свайпом в RecyclerView

Tags: android

Пытаюсь сделать свайп в `RecycerView`. Не просто удаление элемента смахиванием, а чтобы когда справа налево смахивали на элементе отображались кнопки, и только нажав на кнопку "Удалить" или "Изменить" выполнялось действие. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать правильно? Пока что только получилось сделать удаление смахиванием.

Из классов убрала лишний код, чтобы не захламлять вопрос.

item_recipe

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/recyclerview_margin_bottom"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/recyclerview_cardview_corners">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorLightGray"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|end"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/delete_icon"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/edit_icon"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_edit" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/view_foreground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/recycler_item_bg"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="@dimen/recyclerview_padding_all">

            <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgRecipe"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/recyclerview_img_size"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/no_image_bg"
                app:riv_corner_radius="@dimen/recyclerview_img_corners" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:padding="@dimen/recyclerview_padding_all"
                android:text="@string/text_recipe"
                android:textSize="@dimen/recyclerview_text_size"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

RecipeAdapter

```
public class RecipeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecipeAdapter.RecipeViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private List<Recipe> recipeList;
    private List<Recipe> mFilteredList;
    private Context mContext;

    OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(long id);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    public RecipeAdapter(Context context, List<Recipe> recipeList, OnRecipeItemFavoritesClick favoritesClick){
        this.recipeList = recipeList;
        this.mFilteredList = recipeList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public class RecipeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public RoundedImageView imgRecipe;
        public TextView txtRecipe;
        public ImageButton btnFavorites;
        public CardView view_foreground;
        public RelativeLayout view_background;
        private OnRecipeItemFavoritesClick favoritesClick;

        public RecipeViewHolder(final View itemView, OnRecipeItemFavoritesClick favoritesClick) {
            super(itemView);

            txtRecipe = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
             imgRecipe = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgRecipe);
            view_background = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_background);
            view_foreground = itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_foreground);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch (view.getId()) {
                default:
                    mItemClickListener.onItemClick(mFilteredList.get(getAdapterPosition()).getId());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecipeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_recipe,parent,false);
        RecipeViewHolder vh = new RecipeViewHolder(v, favoritesClick);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecipeViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        final Recipe recipe = mFilteredList.get(position);
        holder.txtRecipe.setText(recipe.getTitle());

    }

    public List<Recipe> getRecipeList() {
        return mFilteredList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return mFilteredList.size();
    }

    public void restoreItem(Recipe recipe, int position) {
        mFilteredList.add(position, recipe);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        mFilteredList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {

                String charString = charSequence.toString();

                if (charString.isEmpty()) {

                    mFilteredList = recipeList;
                } else {

                    ArrayList<Recipe> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (Recipe recipe : recipeList) {

                        if (recipe.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(charString)) {

                            filteredList.add(recipe);
                        }
                    }

                    mFilteredList = filteredList;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = mFilteredList;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                mFilteredList = (ArrayList<Recipe>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Класс для реализации свайпа

```
public class RecyclerItemTouchHelper extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {
    private RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener listener;

    public RecyclerItemTouchHelper(int dragDirs, int swipeDirs, RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener listener) {
        super(dragDirs, swipeDirs);
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSelectedChanged(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
        if (viewHolder != null) {
            final View foregroundView = ((RecipeAdapter.RecipeViewHolder) viewHolder).view_foreground;

            getDefaultUIUtil().onSelected(foregroundView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY,
                                int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        final View foregroundView = ((RecipeAdapter.RecipeViewHolder) viewHolder).view_foreground;
        getDefaultUIUtil().onDrawOver(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY,
                actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }

    @Override
    public void clearView(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        final View foregroundView = ((RecipeAdapter.RecipeViewHolder) viewHolder).view_foreground;
        getDefaultUIUtil().clearView(foregroundView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(Canvas c, RecyclerView recyclerView,
                            RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY,
                            int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        final View foregroundView = ((RecipeAdapter.RecipeViewHolder) viewHolder).view_foreground;

        getDefaultUIUtil().onDraw(c, recyclerView, foregroundView, dX, dY,
                actionState, isCurrentlyActive);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
        listener.onSwiped(viewHolder, direction, viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public int convertToAbsoluteDirection(int flags, int layoutDirection) {
        return super.convertToAbsoluteDirection(flags, layoutDirection);
    }

    public interface RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener {
        void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction, int position);
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, RecyclerItemTouchHelper.RecyclerItemTouchHelperListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ***

        ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallbackLeft = new RecyclerItemTouchHelper(0, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT, this);
        new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallbackLeft).attachToRecyclerView(rvRecipe);

        ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback itemTouchHelperCallbackRight = new RecyclerItemTouchHelper(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT, this);
        new ItemTouchHelper(itemTouchHelperCallbackRight).attachToRecyclerView(rvRecipe);

    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction, int position) {
        if (viewHolder instanceof RecipeAdapter.RecipeViewHolder) {
            // get the removed item name to display it in snack bar
            String recipeTitle = recipeAdapter.getRecipeList().get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getTitle();

            // backup of removed item for undo purpose
            final Recipe deletedItem = recipeAdapter.getRecipeList().get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
            final int deletedIndex = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

            // remove the item from recycler view
            recipeAdapter.removeItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());

            // showing snack bar with Undo option
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                    .make(getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView(), recipeTitle + " removed from cart!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            snackbar.setAction("UNDO", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    // undo is selected, restore the deleted item
                    recipeAdapter.restoreItem(deletedItem, deletedIndex);
                }
            });
            snackbar.setActionTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            snackbar.show();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проще будет использовать библиотеку, например https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout Ну или на основе нее написать свою реализацию.

Comment: Спасибо. По примеру тут https://medium.com/@velmm/android-recyclerview-with-swipe-menu-example-86259df97907 получилось